# IE runs JavaScript only after pressing F12

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have a strange problem in Internet Explorer with JavaScript. In every browser I did the test the JavaScript is enabled, but it seems to run only after I press the <kbd>F12</kbd>, running it in debug mode. And what is more confusing, after starting the IE debugger everything is working as suppose to.

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're calling:

```
console.log('...some text here...');
```

or any related method of console without having checked if `window.console` exists, the script will fail silently. Opening the console leads to `window.console` existing, which allows the script to continue execution.

Add `"window.console && "` before your calls to `console`:

```
window.console && console.log('works');
```

Comment: Or, just write a wrapper method: `function log(s){ window.console && console.log(s); }`, to keep the code readable...

Comment: thanks guys :D i will keep in mind that from IE family only IE9 has a console :P

Comment: @Constantine, that's not true. Any IE version can have a dynamically added console with firebug lite.

Comment: this is so good! thanks man.. i mean, if it would not cost me such much lifetime and nerves it would actually funny how many different bugs the fkn IE always has

Comment: actually Firefox did this too not so long ago. I actually thought it still does without Firebug (though it would not fail *silently*)

Comment: Great info... had no idea about this